# C# Asynchronous Socket Read Without Using Runtime's Threadpool

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a socket server which can handle relatively large amount of clients. There are different approaches used for such a task, first is to use a separate thread for each incoming connection, and second is to use async/await pattern.

First approach is bad as there will be relatively small number of threads such as all system's resources will be lost on context switching.

Second approach from the first sight is good as we can have our own threadpool with limited number of worker threads, so dispatcher will receive incoming connections, add them to some queue and call async socket read methods which in turn will receive data from socket and add this data/errors to queue for further processing(error handling client responses, DB-related work).

There is not so much info on internal implementation of async/await I could found, but as I understood while using non-UI application all continuation is done through TaskScheduler.Current which is using runtime's threadpool and so it's resources are limited. Greater amount of incoming connections will result in no free threads in runtime's threadpool or amount will be so large that system will stop responding.

In this matter async/await will result in same problem as with 1-client/1-thread concern, however with little advantage as runtime threadpool's threads may not occupy so much address space as default System.Threading.Thread (I believe 1MB stack size + ~1/2MB of control data).

Is there any way I can made one thread to wait for some kernel interrupt on say 10 sockets so application will only use my explicitly sized thread pool? (I mean that in case there is any further data on one from 10 sockets, one thread will wake up and handle it.)

Comment: Asynchronous socket methods all use an IOCP that is built-in to the .NET thread pool, which will probably work just fine for you. No need for your own thread pool.

Comment: The need of my own thread pool comes from the fact I need to do a lot of work with received data and talk back to clients, as a number of callback stuff which is not even related to my app is made using runtime's threadpool, I would like async methods to do as little work as possible.

Comment: I don't see anything in that description that would necessitate a custom thread pool. The built-in one should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

> In this matter async/await will result in same problem as with 1-client/1-thread concern

When thread reach code that is running asynchronously then control is returned to caller so that means thread is returned to thread pool and can handle another request so it is any superior to 1-client/1-thread because thread isn't blocked.

There is some any intersting blog about asnyc/await:
[1](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)